# Associate simple products to configurable products programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, simple-product

This is my first post here, and my first month of learning Magento 2.

I've been able to create configurable and simple products using PHP, but I can't find a way to associate those simple products to a configurable product.
The only resource I've found about it [is this one](http://webkul.com/blog/magento2-assign-existing-associated-products-to-configurable-product/).

But still, I couldn't make it work.

Basically I've created a custom product attribute for the sizes (later on I'll manually look into how to do it programmatically) and I have created products so that the end result is that you see one product of which you can choose multiple sizes.

This is just like Magento 2 with sample data. I've learned how to do it manually but I couldn't find out how to do it programmatically with PHP.

Are there any pointers that could help me solve this issue?

Comment: the duplicate question referred NOT WORKS, but follow the link in the KAndy answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You need use ConfigurableProductLinks extension attribute for this.

See how Magento developer do it in test fixtures [product_configurable.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/_files/product_configurable.php)